# Access NavigationForm, how to navigate to a new record on Load of every Form in?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I Created multible Forms from  tabels with subforms of a querys, with some function. And everything works fine.
Now I need those forms in a navigation form, but some codes cause errors.

In every form i have the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Me.Name, acNewRec
End Sub
```

How schould I change it to work from the navigation form?

I tried:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm,, acNewRec
```

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Forms!NavForm!form_name, acNewRec
```

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Forms!NavForm!navSubform, acNewRec
```

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, Forms!NavForm!navSubform.Form, acNewRec
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread (all of it) to see if it helps. You may only need to set the form's Data Entry property to True instead of using your DoCmd. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onload-go-to-new-record/0d8d200a-e3fa-4f26-a3fd-44e28176bae7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself in 2 ways:

- with a macro instead of VBA
  in Form Events -> on Load -> Set macro to go to a new record.
- with VBA:

  ```
  Forms!NavigationFormName.NavSubform.SetFocus
  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
  ```